# How can i nest marko components in the file tree

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, marko

i dont know how to access components that are nested in the components folder in my app's root index component. what i expected was that i can reference them via a nested html tag

i have a very solid functional react background and try to create my first marko widget.

index.marko

```
<div>
  <typography/headline />
  <typography/body />
</div>
```

the file tree:

```
src/
  index.marko
  components/
    typography/
      headline/
        index.marko
      body/
         index.marko
[...]
```

this does not work as the tag is unrecognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marko doesn't support nesting like this, so you'd need to do this instead:

```
<div>
  <typography-headline />
  <typography-body />
</div>
```

```
src/
  index.marko
  components/
    typography-headline/
      index.marko
    typography-body/
      index.marko
```